# Replacing Slide Library in 2013

Tags: office-365

I have a system on SP 2010 that is going to be upgraded to 2013. However, it appears Slide Library has been deprecated (http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint-help/discontinued-features-and-modified-functionality-in-microsoft-sharepoint-2013-HA102892827.aspx#_Toc349821245). I've read about solutions to access it in 2013, but it's a back door and not guaranteed to be there.

Does anyone have a suggestion for a replacement for Slide Library in 2013? We use it to ensure that our multiple presentations, when they share a data point, are updated in *all* presentations...

Any thoughts?

Comment: I too am faced with this situation as we were heavily using slide libraries. It doesn't look like there's any 3rd party support for this... My organization will likely have to adapt to fit Microsoft's will. We are migrating sites now via Idera SharePoint Migration suite. We used site template mapping feature to change slide libraries over to regular document libraries and it's working great so far. Only problem i've noticed is that default views aren't working properly.

Comment: have you found a solution in the meantime? I'd like to use slide libraries in a new SharePoint 2013 site, but I'm reluctant, as this feature is not officially supported any more.

Answer (score 3):

As long as the relations between the presentations are intact updating the slide in one presentation will still update all the others that use that slide. See [the workaround link](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/powerpoint-help/add-a-slide-from-another-presentation-file-HA010210933.aspx). The process of showing each slide as its own document will be gone however. If that is still needed it could be created manually by creating a presentation for each slide.

Answer (score 2):

FWIW.

Revised reply.

The below link shows a workaround.  Missed the sentence and tag above.  Noob here.

Using the link, I have created or walked an end-user through about 40 libraries.  Never had an issue creating one.  This is on a production environment (not O365 like original post).

The libraries have all worked as previous versions.  The functionality of some settings is another matter.  For example, Explorer View on the ribbon while using a 32bit browser did not work.  The libraries' Actions Button Explorer View did.   Missing Library and Browser tab from library.

In our old enviroment (MOSS 2007), Sharepoint and slide library were far from great.  Nothing has changed

http://techtrainingnotes.blogspot.com/2012/11/finding-missing-sharepoint-2013-slide.html

Version 2.0

Comment: Is this an attempt to answer the question? If so, please add the details from the link and shorten of the other content of your answer. If the link breaks your answer will be of no help to future readers